# Loading Canon .CR2 files in .NET

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

I am trying to process Canon RAW .CR2 files using C#.  My code is as follows:

```
BitmapDecoder bmpDec = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(origFile), BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
BitmapEncoder bmpEnc = new BmpBitmapEncoder();
bmpEnc.Frames.Add(bmpDec.Frames[0]);
Stream ms = new MemoryStream();
bmpEnc.Save(ms);
Image srcImage = Bitmap.FromStream(ms);
```

The first few lines seem to run without a hitch, but the line

```
bmEnc.Save(ms);
```

just hangs without completing and without raising any exception.

Has anyone had any success with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't believe BitmapDecoder understands .CR2. It is not a conventional image format by far, as it contains the raw bayer-sensor image (one color per pixel), not a standard image.

If you want to convert CR2 and other camera raw formats, you should look at DCRaw: http://www.cybercom.net/~dcoffin/dcraw/ or libraw (based on dcraw, friendly as a library): http://www.libraw.org/

Comment: OK, .NET wrapper now written.  If I can get it bulletproof I'll post it somewhere for public consumption.

Comment: Hi @DarrenOster, did you make the wrapper publically available in the meantime?

Comment: Yes @DarrenOster. Did you?

Comment: Sorry, no, I never got around to it.  Not even sure where my work-in-progress was.  If I can find it I'll throw it on GitHub, but no promises...

Answer (score 6):

Know this is a old thread but I found a nice easy to use library (Magick.NET).

How to do a conversion:

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("StillLife.CR2"))
{
    image.Write("StillLife.jpg");
}
```

https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET/blob/master/docs/ReadRawImageFromCamera.md

Details of nuget package installation:

```
Install-Package Magick.NET-Q16-AnyCPU
```

https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET

Answer (score 4):

W8.1 or W7 after applying https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=26829 seems to work well

```
var files = Directory.GetFiles(@"D:\DCIM","*.CR2");
            for(var i = 0; i < files.Length; i++) {
                Console.Write("{0,-4}: {1} => ", i, files[i]);
                var bmpDec = BitmapDecoder.Create(new Uri(files[i]), BitmapCreateOptions.DelayCreation, BitmapCacheOption.None);
                var bmpEnc = new JpegBitmapEncoder();
                bmpEnc.QualityLevel = 100;
                bmpEnc.Frames.Add(bmpDec.Frames[0]);
                var oldfn = Path.GetFileName(files[i]);
                var newfn = Path.ChangeExtension(oldfn, "JPG");
                using(var ms = File.Create(Path.Combine(@"D:\DCIM\100CANON", newfn), 10000000)) {
                    bmpEnc.Save(ms);
                }
                Console.WriteLine(newfn);
            }
```

Comment: using (var ms = File.Create(Path.Combine(@"D:\DCIM\100CANON", newfn), 10000000)) . . . . getting error on "File" word:
'Controller.File(byte[], string)' is a method, which is not valid in the given context

Comment: Ok, I had to add "System.IO." in front of "File" word even though using System.IO was already at the top of the page. "The reason for that is because you are writing this code inside a controller action which already defines a File method on the Controller class."

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16188314/why-cant-i-use-system-io-file-methods-in-an-mvc-controller

Comment: That codec from microsoft is not updated since 2014 or 2015. So, it doesn't support newer cameras. One may need to install individual codecs from each manufacturer (eg Nikon) which is not so ideal