# Why can't I use System.IO.File methods in an MVC controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, file

I am trying to see if a file exists before using it in an MVC controller:

```
string path = "content/image.jpg";

if (File.Exists(path))
{ 
    //Other code
}
```

The `File` keyword is underlined in red, and the compiler shows an error:

> `System.Web.MVC.Controller.File(string, string, string)` is a
>   'method', witch is not valid in the given context.

How can I use `File.Exists()` in a controller?

Comment: use `System.IO.File.Exists(...)`

Answer (score 100, accepted):

You should prefix it with a namespace:

```
if (System.IO.File.Exists(picPath))
{ 
    //Other code
}
```

The reason for that is because you are writing this code inside a controller action which already defines a [`File`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492897%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) method on the Controller class.

Comment: Oh thanks so much, Something so simple and took me a hour of pulling my hair out. Thanks for the reasoning provided as well.

Answer (score 0):

In .Net 7 there was an error `CS0234` after updating from .net 6 or renaming the controller namespace, which states in `YourSolutionNamespace.YourControllerName` there is no type or namespace `IO` , which can be solved with a global::

```
/*var stream = */ global::System.IO.File.OpenRead(filePath);
```

directive.