# FreeImage.LoadFromStream fails for a CR2 file

Tags: c#, freeimage

The following code illustrates the problem I am faced with. If I load a CR2 file with

```
var format = FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_RAW;
retVal = FreeImage.LoadBitmap("AJ2A1447.cr2", ref format);
```

then I successfully load the RAW file. If I use something like

```
using (Stream stream = new FileStream("AJ2A1447.cr2", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
  var format = FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_RAW;
  freeImageHandle = FreeImage.LoadFromStream(stream, ref format);
  if (freeImageHandle.IsNull)
  {
    throw new Exception("Unable to load image from stream");
  }

  retVal = FreeImage.GetBitmap(freeImageHandle);
}
```

then I am unsuccessful as freeImageHandle is null. I use FileStream for a test, the real code will use a MemoryStream.

Any clue to why LoadFromStream fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FreeImage uses `libRawLite` to read `Canon CR2` raw format.
However, `libRawLite` does not support the `sRAW` CR2 files.

Comment: I tried with different RAW formats: RAW, SRAW1 and SRAW2 plus with different cameras. Not much of a difference as they all failed. I am successful when I add the load flag: `FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.RAW_PREVIEW` which I know means: "Tries to load the JPEG preview image, embedded in Exif Metadata or load the image as RGB 24-bit if no preview image is available". If I try with  flag `FREE_IMAGE_LOAD_FLAGS.RAW_DISPLAY` then I just get a white BPM out of it. So right now I am trying to figure out if I get some embedded JPEG when I add the PREVIEW flag

Comment: I ended up programming a solution in C++ using Libraw so no longer an issue for me. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

there is number of RAW formats and I doubt if FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_RAW knows how to decode CR2.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raw_image_format

Try to use windows generated bitmap and jpg to see if your code works.

Comment: The LoadBitmap approach shouldn't also fail if this was true? Meaning Freeimage needs to know how to decode the CR2 file in both cases. I use FREE_IMAGE_FORMAT.FIF_RAW in both cases.

Comment: use appropriate formats for bmp and jpg images: FIF_BMP, FIF_JPEG.

Comment: I am trying to load a CR2 file (canon raw format) so I am using the right format.

Comment: I know ;) but test your code against other formats. This should work. I doubt if Canon RAW format is supported.

Comment: Tell me, why the Loadbitmap method wouldn't fail if CR2 format is not supported?

Comment: Lars, Canon CR2 is not supported. .NET don't know how to decode it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111939/loading-canon-cr2-files-in-net

Comment: You do know that Freeimage's .net code is basically only wrapping the C code that does the magic?