# Simple way to convert CR2 image to TIFF in C# code

Tags: c#, tiff, system.drawing

I've spent most of the day trying to find a solution.

A barebones example, (which doesn't work but illustrates my need), would be this:

```
using (var imgRAW = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/Masters/viennaball2009_153.CR2")))
{
    imgRAW.Save(Server.MapPath("/GalleryImages/Masters/Vienna.tiff"));
}
```

or at the least save as a .jpg file.

Comment: Have you tried this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4111939/loading-canon-cr2-files-in-net

Comment: @Rufus, thanks. Yes I have tried that before I posted this. If you see at the bottom of the accepted solution I mention that I found the using statement that references the objects involved but they are for windows forms, not MVC. Unless I am wrong. Which is possible.

Comment: I got everything hooked up without any red lines but I get this error that I can't solve:
"The image cannot be decoded. The image header might be corrupted."